# Select all records between two dates created between time of day - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm using Laravel 3 - PHP and MySQl.

I need to select all records created between two dates (`created_at` DATETIME) and between two times (3pm and 6pm).

`$query->where_between('created_at', $this->s['start'], $this->s['end']);`

How can I add a time range to that for between 3pm and 6pm between those days?

### Edit

```
$this->s['start'] = '2014-2-14';

$this->s['end'] = '2014-2-16';
```

Timerange: 06:00:00 and 09:00:00 UTC

Dates are stored in Datetime like `2014-2-15 06:43:56`

### Example data

Records:

Between `2014-2-14` and `2014-2-17` AND between `07:00:00` and `14:00:00`.

- 2014-2-15 06:43:56
- 2014-2-16 08:43:56*
- 2014-2-17 15:43:56
- 2014-2-17 10:43:56*
- 2014-2-18 12:43:56
- 2014-2-19 14:43:56
- 2014-2-20 16:43:56

`*` selected record

Along the lines of:

`` $query->raw_where('EXTRACT(HOUR_SECOND from `created_at`) between 070000 and 140000'); ``

Simpler way to do this?

Comment: What is in your `$this->s['start'` and `$this->s['end'`, value ?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not doing this using sql? Filtering is part and parcel of SQLs raison d'etre. Indeed, the [between](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) clause exists for precisely this reason:

```
SELECT pkid from tbl where datetime_field between 7:00:00 and 14:00:00
```

I'd recommend keeping the filtering as close to the database as is reasonably possible, given the constraints of the database itself.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you just have to add an other where_between constraint to your request :

```
$query->where_between('created_at', $this->s['start'], $this->s['end'])
      ->where_between('created_at', '6:00:00', '9:00:00');
```

Never tried but it should do the job !

Thanks to hd1 for SQL tip.